# Symfony2 How to get the selected value from a select field with twig

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-2.3

I have a form that has some bootstrap nav-tabs and I need to repeat in every nav-tabs some info that I have preloaded from a select type field.

I can access to the Id with

```
{{  dump(form.proveedor.vars.value) }}
```

But I need the selected label value. How can I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hopefully I get you question correctly.

```
    {% set label = '' %}
    {% for choice in form.proveedor.vars.choices %}
        {% if choice.value == form.proveedor.vars.value %}
            {% set label = choice.label %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

    {{ label }}
```

Comment: Thanks man!!! I was struggling with this. I pasted your code directly to mine and it worked just perfectly.

Where can I find documentation about this? Or how can I find it?

Thanks to you too @repincln

Comment: Best way is just dump variables and find out if value you wanted is stored somewhere in view already. If not, just prepared it in controller.

Comment: I dont know if my dump var is working fine because it doesnt show anything when I looking for array values, so I couldnt see the list of posible value

Answer (score 0):

selected is an attribute, so you can access it with:

```
{{ dump(form.proveedor.vars.attr["selected"]) }}
```

Then you can with if sentence check if option has attr equal to selected. If yes then do something, like echo label.

```
{% if form.proveedor.vars.attr["selected"] == "selected" %}
  {# do something, like echo label #}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Its a select field. I can see all the values with {{  dump(form.proveedor.vars.choices) }} but I can't take the label of a selected value preloaded from db

Comment: Are you passing form results back to controller?

Comment: yeap!  I have done it with jquery but I dont like this way. Any idea how to access it with twig?

Comment: I edited my question. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I want to access the <option selected="selected">HELLO WORLD!</option> from a select type field.

Comment: But I want to access to the value "Hello World!". How can I do this?