# get the id of selected index using set jquery and twig

Tags: jquery, symfony, twig

I want to get the id from a dropdownmenu list using jquery and the function set

```
var c = document.getElementById("dropdown1");
var id= parseInt(c.selectedIndex) ;
```

but i want to get the id using this method

```
{% set id=parseInt(c.selectedIndex) %}
```

but does not work

in fact this is my real problematic: I have a drowpdown menu list generated from and entity

```
->add(
            'predefinedMessage',
            'entity',
            array(
                'empty_value' => 'Ajouter un message Prédéfini',
                'class' => 'MyBundle:PredefinedMessage',
                'property' => 'name',
                'multiple' => false,
                'error_bubbling' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($user) {

                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                        ->where('u.user = :user')
                        ->setParameter('user', $user);

                },

            )
```

the message entity has many field such as: id, message, name

[image]

so in jquery, I want to get the message value of the selected index

my code in jquery is as follow:

```
var c = document.getElementById("predefinedMessage");

    var id= parseInt(c.selectedIndex) ;

    var text= "{{ form.predefinedMessage.vars.choices[id].data.message }}";
```

but always I gor an error, and the id is not defined.

any help please for this problem

Comment: `$('#dropdown1 option:selected').val()` ?

Comment: I want to get the id using set like {% set id=parseInt(c.selectedIndex) %}

Comment: You have got your concepts really, really wrong. You are trying to mix twig and javascript. The first executes in the server while the second executes in the client browser. It is possible to generate something with twig which will be used by javascript, but it cannot be possible the other way around. By the time the javascript code runs, the twig code has already been executed at the server.

Comment: You can not get this value in twig. Dropdown item is selected on the client side after template was rendered on the server.

Comment: please see the update question to understand the real problematic, i'm sure that the question is very important and can help many others developer. I can't fount any response for this question.

Comment: @MajdiTaleb you continue to have your concepts really mixed and wrong.  You are getting the id in javascript and then you are trying to use it in a twig expression!! The twig code was already executed at the server by the time the javascript code runs. What you are trying to do is just **impossible**

Comment: thank you very much carlos, I will use ajax to perfom this action

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, it's impossible to get a value from javascript back to the twig template, because the twig template is being rendered and the result sent to the client and only then, the resulting javascript will be executed.

Now, if you just need to display the *initial* value of the select box (the value that is pre-selected when the page loads), you can access that in twig without the need for javascript. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26718986/symfony2-how-to-get-the-selected-value-from-a-select-field-with-twig) question for how to do that.

If you need the selected value to dynamically change as the user selects something different, you have to use javascript or jquery, but you can't pass the value back to a twig variable, you have to insert it somewhere in the DOM using jQuery. If you want this to update dynamically, you need to put this code into a 'change' event handler.

```
var selectBox = $("#id_of_your_select_box");
selectBox.change(function(){
    var selectedValue = selectBox.val();
    $("#id_of_where_the_value_is_displayed").text(selectedValue);
});
```

Comment: thnak you very much for your answer, I solved my problem using ajax, first I get the id of the selected option , and then I use ajax to get the value of message field in the predefinedMessage entity. If you look in the form type, you see that I added an entity as field. so when I select an option, for example 1, I should get the message value of this entity. my entity have 3 field: id, name, message. thank at all